# Необходимый минимум знаний у C# junior

Tags: обсуждение, диалоги-о-работе

На данный момент неспешно изучаю С# и немного С++.
Мне интересен необходимый багаж знании у С# разработчика.
Нашел подобную тему [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/23535/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-junior-java-developer), но там по Java человек спрашивает. 
Кто если уже работает или работал по C# распишите минимальный багаж знаний для джуниора в С#.

Comment: Добавьте Linq, замените Hibernate на EF, spring на asp.net, JDBC на ADO - а остальное в списке к языку не относится и является вполне соответствующим.

Comment: Разве джуниор - не ничего не знающий стажёр? =) Тогда он должен знать всё)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

#### Дисклеймер

Вообще, требования для Junior-разработчика имеют неплохой разброс. На это влияют:

- Компания, в которую вы попадете
- Команда, в которую вы попадете
- Проект, в который вы попадете

Требования могут выдвигаться как на уровне компании (например, высшее техническое образование или язык коммуникаций) на уровне команды (возможно, некий специфический опыт), так и на проектном уровне (его технологический стек). Это всё говорит о том, что само *понятие Junior весьма субъективно* и общих требований здесь быть не может. С одним и тем же техническим бакграундом вы запросто можете устроиться в компанию `ASoftware` и провалить собеседование в `BSoftware`. Поэтому, дальнейшие рассуждения о требованиях к Junor-разработчику я буду вести через призму своего опыта и опыта тех команд, в которых я работал (что никак не может являться истиной в последней инстанции. Пожалуйста, понимайте это перед тем, как брать текст ниже за руководство к действию)

#### Отделить мух от котлет

Мне кажется несколько ошибочным концентрироваться на знаниях конкретных технологий при собеседовании младшего разработчика. Под понятием «конкретные технологии» я имею ввиду знаний **конкретных** UI-фреймворков, ORM или IoС-контейнеров или ещё сотню библиотек и фреймворков. Мне кажется странным вопрос на собеседовании «Расскажите, как бы вы это сделали на EFramework?»

Мне было бы важнее понять не то, сколько технологий вы знаете сейчас, а то, как быстро вы можете осваивать новые технологии вообще. Поэтому, я бы больше сконцентрировался на знаниях `C#` и `CLR` и `понимании проблем`, которые решают конкретные технологии. Например, если вы в резюме напишете, что знаете, Ninject, то мы с вами, скорее всего, будем разговаривать про DIP в целом и проблемы DI в частности.

Книги по теме:

- Эндрю Троелсен. «[Язык программирования C# 6.0 и платформа .NET 4.6](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/137598683/)»

Для повышения знаний:

- Братья Албахари. «[С# 6.0 Справочник Языка](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/135794222/)»
- Джеффри Рихтер. «[CLR via C#](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/21236101/)»
- Джон Скит. «[C# in Depth](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/27933250/)»

#### Обеспечить внешнее качество

Минимум, на который рассчитывает среднестатистическая компания (спорный момент, кстати) это возможность продать результат вашего труда и заработать деньги. С этой точки зрения, вы обязаны обеспечивать внешнее качество вашего кода (он работает и решает задачу для которой был написан) для этого вам нужно понимать концепции тестирования и уметь их применять. Вы должны понимать для чего нужны различные типы тестов (модульные/интеграционные/приёмочные) и какое влияние оказывают модульные тесты на код. Одно из требований *в нашей* команде — код должен быть покрыт тестами. Без выполнения этого требования код не может пройти ревью.

Книги по теме:

- Рой Ошерув. «[The Art Of Unit Testing](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/136632098/)»

Для повышения знаний

- Джерард Месарош. «[xUnit Test Patterns: Refactoring Test Code](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/4127815/)»

#### Обеспечить внутреннее качество

Мы живем в таком мире, где мы постоянно решаем две задачи: как заработать деньги сейчас и как заработать их потом. С точки зрения нашей отрасли, для того, что бы зарабатывать деньги «потом» нужно:

1. Уметь передавать информацию о системе через код, для того, что бы с легкостью вносить в неё изменения в будущем.
2. Код должен быть покрыт тестами для того, что бы у нас была уверенность, что эти изменения не приведут к регрессии.

Сконцентрируемся на первом пункте. Если вы поняли, то это про ООП и [ООД](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5?veaction=edit&section=1) в частности. Минимум, на который нужно рассчитывать — знание принципов ООП (инкапсуляция, наследование, полиморфизм). Особая важность в понимании *полиморфизма* и умении организовывать логичные и уместные иерархии наследования.

*Особый навык*, — умение решать проблемы дизайна кода и устранять различные [code smells](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%81_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC) при помощи [S.O.L.I.D.](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)) Где-то рядом тут пересекаются шаблоны проектирования. Было бы здорово если вы будете знакомы с [GoF-паттернами](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns), ну или как-минимум знать по паре самых распространенных на категорию. Но, наверное, это уже не про Junoir'a.

Книги по теме:

- Роберт Мартин. «[Чистый код](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/21916535/)»
- Роберт Мартин. «[Принципы, паттерны и методики гибкой разработки на языке C#](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/5800704/)»
- [Сергей Тепляков](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178188/sergey-teplyakov). «[Паттерны проектирования на платформе .NET](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/31789305/)»

Для повышения знаний

- GoF. «[Приемы объектно-ориентированного проектирования](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/2457392/)»

Comment: И зачем вы перенесли вопрос сюда? И почему сейчас, а не сразу?

Comment: Я не переносил, но скажу сразу на вопрос "зачем": это вопрос "неформат" не подходит по правилам. Но так как подобные вопросы могут представлять ценность для некоторых людей, то когда-то было принято решение переносить такие вопросы на мету.

Comment: Уважаемый модератор! Этот ответ я как раз писал для «сайта программистов», так как считаю что он там логичен и уместен. Если бы я хотел что-то написать для меты я бы обязательно это сделал.

Comment: @АртёмОконечников дело в том, что вопросы вида "минимум знаний у C# junior" - это оффтопик на основном сайте. Такие вопросы [регулярно задаются и регулярно закрываются как оффтопик](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5BC%23%5D+is%3Aquestion+junior). Т.е. у меня был выбор - удалить или перенести на мету. Т.к. вы успели дать развернутый ответ - я решил перенести. Перенес не сразу - модераторы тоже люди, им нужно иногда спать :)

Comment: @АртёмОконечников если вы считаете, что на основном сайте не хватало *еще одного* обсуждения "что должен знать джуниор", в ответ на который будут постить очередные списки "джуниор должен знать и хорошо понимать SOLID/Паттерны/ООП/ООД, уметь писать тесты, настраивать CI/СD и вообще быть минимум Mid-ом, а желательно - сеньером" - создайте обсуждение на мете и предложите сделать такие вопросы онтопиком :(

Comment: «минимум Mid-ом, а желательно - сеньером» — cпасибо, что добавил от себя, Паша. Но я как-нибудь без обсуждений на мете обойдусь.

Comment: Повторяться не стоит, думаю, так как такое обсуждение уже было и сообщество выступило против подобных "списков" http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2928/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2

Comment: @АртёмОконечников тут проблема не в том, что ответ плохой. И не в том, что вопрос плохой. Вроде и тема интересная (все же были джуниорами), и ответы попадаются хорошие (ответ выше - очень хороший, он задает правильное направление, я плюсанул). Но обычно такой вопрос скатывается в что-то непонятное, с прямо противоположными советами, и никто не знает что с этим делать. Пройдись по "junior" в поиске - там половина ответов - непонятный мусор :( Сплошное "Готовиться не нужно" и "купи книгу" :(. Удалять нельзя, оставлять нельзя, переносить - можно, но обидно (репутация за ответ теряется)